# Laravel Echo not receiving Pusher event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-echo

I am having trouble with Laravel Echo to listener to Pusher channels. I am not able to get any response in my browser (no console log).

In my bootstrap.js I got.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: 'myPusherAppKey',
     cluster: 'mt1', //My app is US-EAST
     encrypted: true
});
```

I use my browser console and type:

```
Echo.channel('my-channel')
    .listen('my-event', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

I can see from the Pusher Debug Console that

1. CONNECTION My app
2. SUBSCRIBED My-channel
3. OCCUPIED My-channel

I then use the Pusher Debug Console to send the default event:

```
Channel: my-channel 
Event: my-event
Data: {
       "name": "John",
       "message": "Hello"
       }
```

**However, I do not get any output in my browser console**.

If I further type in my browser console:

```
Echo.leave('my-channel');
```

I can see from Pusher Debug Console

1. UNSUBSCRIBED my-channel
2. VACATED my-channel

How can I get Laravel Echo to listen to Pusher events?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was a Namespace issue. [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#listening-for-events) explains it.

> Echo will automatically assume the events are located in the  App\Events namespace

Therefore, the event name must be changed in the Pusher Debug Console as such:

```
Event: App\Events\my-event
```